# Fault in Ajax php search

Tags: php, ajax

In the following Ajax based search box, if the character is at position 0 then the respective name in the array is not returning but for characters at other positions everything works well. Please fix this...

PHP

```
$query = $_GET['query'];

$names = array('abc', 'hello', 'cool', 'fun', 'demo', 'test');
foreach($names as $name)
{
$str = strpos($name, $query);

if(!empty($str))
{
    echo "$name ";

}

}
```

HTML

```
<form name='myForm'>
Name: <input type='text' onblur="ajaxFunction(this.value);" name='username' /> <br />
Time: <input type='text' disabled="disabled" name='time' />
</form>
```

AJAX

```
function ajaxFunction(val) {
var ajaxRequest;

try {
    //Opera, Safari and Firefox xml object
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
} catch(e) {
    try {
        //Internet Explorer xml object
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch(e) {
        try {
            //Old browser's xml object
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");                   
        } catch(e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

}

ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        document.myForm.time.value = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    } else {
        //do nothing
    }
}
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "names.php?query="+val, true);
ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
```

Comment: can you tell me what is returning for what ? and in which example of input its not working ?

Comment: Example: If you type `a`, value abc not returning from names array...

Comment: @BhavinRana but for `b` or `c` it returns `abc`, same is the case with other names...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following -

```
if($str !== FALSE)
{
   echo "$name ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's maybe of the 0 Value returned by strpos (it returns an integer) ... i mean the "if" statement could value it as a false.

Try to compare like

```
if(strpos($name, $query) === false){ .... do something..... }
```